# Check if string contains strictly a string

Tags: c#, string, contains

I've a string looking like this : str =  P1|P2|P3....

I need to check if the string contains for instance P1.
I do that :

```
if (str.Contains("P1"))
{...}
```

My issue comes when I look for P1 and str does not contains P1 but P10, it returns true, which is logical, but not what I need.

How can I check strictly for P1 without returning true if I have P10 in the string.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure that `str` is the most logical way to be holding this data? Why are you not using some collection type which can hold multiple values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string into array and then check like this

```
bool bFound = str.split('|').Contains("p1")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check for `P10` as well, then do so in reverse order, which means you'd pick up `P10` before `P1`.

If every `Psomething` is followed by a `|` you can check for `P1|`. This won't work if it's a separator and won't appear at the very end of the string.

A regex would be another solution:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "P1(?!\d)") // Matches P1 if not followed by another digit
```

Generally, if you run into this problem, it's a poor choice of data structures, though. A string isn't exactly a collection of things and that's what you're trying to model here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not split the string and check against that:

```
string input = "P1|P2|P3|P10";

string[] split = input.Split('|'); // { "P1", "P2", "P3", "P10" }

bool containsP1 = split.Contains("P1"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.Split('|').Contains("P1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good case for using a regex, as you need to make sure that the string you are looking for is delimited by either a pipe or the end of the string.

For example:

```
string input = "P1|P2|P3|P10";
string pattern = @"P1(\||$)";
Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if string you are looking for is followed by '|' or is at the end of the string in which you check.

```
String str = "P1|P3|P20";
String strToFind = "P2";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(str, strToFind+@"(\||\Z)");
```